# log file not being created in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I am trying to configure logger in my spring MVC application but somehow it doesn't seems to work. I am using [Log4j 1.2.17](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17) and have created a properties file for the configuration inside resource folder. The file contents are as below:

```
 Root logger option
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ERROR, stdout, file

 # Redirect log messages to a log file
 log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

 #outputs to Tomcat home
 log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/vshukla/Documents/softwares/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/logs/prismweb.log
 log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
 log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
 log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This is how i initiate the logger in each class:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);
```

And just to test, am adding some simple error cases to my controller method but despite giving complete path, log file is not created.

Controller code:

```
    try{
       int i=1/0;
       System.out.println(i);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error:", new Exception("Init method"));
    }
```

I also tried creating a `prismweb.log` file inside tomcat logs folder but when I run, nothing is logged in the file and it's empty. What is wrong with my approach or my configuration?

Comment: for you link : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/

Comment: I followed the link only.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml try to exclude the commons-logging in your spring core or spring mvc dependencies :

```
<!-- 1. exclude commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did that. No luck.